# Deriving Time Complexity from an algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, code-analysis

I am trying to learn about time complexity of an algorithm. My professor has pushed it beyond Big O and wants us to be able to derive an algorithm to a mathematical function. I am having a hard time conceptualizing how this is done and was looking for help. In my class notes, a selection sort algorithm was provided (as shown in the code below). The notes asked the following question: **"Derive a function f(n) that corresponds to the total number of times that *minIndex or any position of nums* is modified in the worst case.** Now the notes tell me the answer is **f(n)= 1/2n^2 + 5/2n + 3**. I was wondering if anyone could explain how this occurs.

My professor told us to count the operations in the inner loop and work our way out. so I believe that at worst case in the inner loop the if statement always executes, this would mean we run the loop n-i-1 times, I get these values by taking n (the boundary that the for loop has to be less than and subtracting it by the starting condition (i+1). Then I look at the outer loop and I see it goes from i until it reaches n-1, so it could be written as (n-1)-i or just like the inner loop, n-i-1. Looking further there are three modifications in the outer loop so we get (n-i-1)+3 ( could I write it as (n-i+2)?

The number of modification at the worst case for the inner loop:
n-i-1

The number of modifications at the worst case for the outer loop:
(n-i-1)+3

now I would like to know how do you go from counting the two different modifications done and becoming f(n)= 1/2n^2 + 5/2n + 3.

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] nums) {

        int n = nums.length;
        int minIndex;

        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            //find the index of themin number.
            minIndex = i;

            for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
                if(nums[j] < nums[minIndex]) {
                    minIndex = j;
                }
                int temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[minIndex];
                nums[minIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How many times does **outer loop** run?
**`n - 1` times**.

How many times does inner loop run, for each iteration of outer loop?
From `n - 1` times down to `1` time, as outer loop progresses, so on average:
`((n - 1) + 1) / 2` = `n / 2` times.

So, how many times does **inner loop** run in **total**?
`(n - 1) * (n / 2)` = **`n^2 / 2 - n / 2` times**.

How many times is `minIndex` modified?
Once per outer loop + once per inner loop:
`(n - 1) + (n^2 / 2 - n / 2)` = `n^2 / 2 + n / 2 - 1` times.

How many times is a position of `nums` modified?
Twice per inner loop:
`2 * (n^2 / 2 - n / 2)` = `n^2 - n` times.

What is **total** number of **modifications**?
`(n^2 / 2 + n / 2 - 1) + (n^2 - n)` = **`(3*n^2 - n) / 2 - 1` times**.
Or `1½n² - ½n - 1`

---

That's not the same answer as you said your notes has, so let's prove it.

First, we add debug printing, i.e. print any modification including a modification number.

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] nums) {
                                              int mod = 0;
    int n = nums.length;
    int minIndex;

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        //find the index of themin number.
        minIndex = i;                         System.out.printf("%2d: minIndex = %d%n", ++mod, i);

        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if(nums[j] < nums[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = j;                 System.out.printf("%2d: minIndex = %d%n", ++mod, j);
            }
            int temp = nums[i];
            nums[i] = nums[minIndex];         System.out.printf("%2d: nums[%d] = %d%n", ++mod, i, nums[minIndex]);
            nums[minIndex] = temp;            System.out.printf("%2d: nums[%d] = %d%n", ++mod, minIndex, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Worst case is sorting an array of descending numbers, so lets try 3 numbers:

```
int[] nums = { 3, 2, 1 };
selectionSort(nums);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

We'd expect `(3*n^2 - n) / 2 - 1` = `(3*3^2 - 3) / 2 - 1` = `24 / 2 - 1` = `11` modifications.

```
 1: minIndex = 0
 2: minIndex = 1
 3: nums[0] = 2
 4: nums[1] = 3
 5: minIndex = 2
 6: nums[0] = 1
 7: nums[2] = 2
 8: minIndex = 1
 9: minIndex = 2
10: nums[1] = 2
11: nums[2] = 3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Yup, 11 modifications.

Lets try 9:

```
int[] nums = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

`(3*n^2 - n) / 2 - 1` = `(3*9^2 - 9) / 2 - 1` = `234 / 2 - 1` = `116` modifications.

```
  1: minIndex = 0
  2: minIndex = 1
  3: nums[0] = 8
  4: nums[1] = 9
  5: minIndex = 2
  6: nums[0] = 7
      . . .
111: nums[6] = 7
112: nums[8] = 8
113: minIndex = 7
114: minIndex = 8
115: nums[7] = 8
116: nums[8] = 9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Yup, 116 modification.

Formula verified by empiric evidence:
**`f(n) = (3*n^2 - n) / 2 - 1`**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Was very thorough and really helped me understand what was going on!

Comment: @AhmedKidwai If you found the answer *useful*, you should click the up-arrow to the left of the answer. --- You should also accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, so others can see that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.